# python sqlite3 UPDATE set from variables

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-update

I made next Query to update a row in my DB.

```
def saveData(title, LL, LR, RL, RR, distanceBack):
    c.execute("UPDATE settings SET (?,?,?,?,?,?) WHERE name=?",(title, LL, LR, RL, RR, distanceBack, title))
    conn.commit()
```

I always get next error: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
I know something isn't correct with the question marks. I can't find out what the exact solution is. Can somebody explain me what the problem is?

Comment: what you are trying to do with this function is format a string that will then be the query to be executed. Apparently the string formatting is working very well.. You can try this: `c.execute("UPDATE settings SET ({},{},{},{},{},{}) WHERE name={}".format(title, LL, LR, RL, RR, distanceBack, title))`. When using string formatting to form queries that are executed by a DB you have to be careful of the injections you are allowing. If this will be used by other people too, you have to do some reading..

Comment: Are you sure that in sqlite that syntax is valid ? I guess, maybe, you can try: UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2...., columnN = valueN
WHERE [condition];

Comment: probably your `UPDATE` syntax is wrong - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Answer (score 8):

You could use this SQL syntax:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2...., columnN = valueN
WHERE [condition];
```

for example, if you have a table called Category and you want to edit the category name you can use:

```
c.execute("UPDATE CATEGORY SET NAME=? WHERE ID=?", (name,category_id))
```

WHERE:

Category is a table that contains only two items: (ID, NAME) with ID PRIMARY KEY.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this simply adding column name as a string in the query

```
import sqlite3

def updatedata():
    conn=sqlite3.connect('SCHOOL.db')
    cur=conn.cursor()
    rno=int(input('Enter roll number whose data to be changed'))
    column=input("enter column to be updated")
    value=int(input("enter value to set"))
    query='UPDATE STUDENT SET '+column+ ' = ? WHERE Rollno = ?'
    cur.execute(query,(value,rno))
    conn.commit()
    print("Record Updated successfully")
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question (and if anyone else is wondering)

> Can somebody explain me what the problem is?

I believe it most likely has to do with what version of SQLite your python installation is using.
The official SQLite documentation says in its [UPDATE documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html):

> Beginning in SQLite version 3.15.0 (2016-10-14), an assignment in the SET clause can be a parenthesized list of column names on the left and a row value of the same size on the right.

So you can check what version of SQLite your Python installation is using like this:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.8.11'  # return value from my python 2.7.14 installation
```

Which means I won't be able to use the syntax `SET (column1, column2) = (value1, value2)` and instead I'd have to use the syntax `SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It may be depend on versions used! The following code works for:

- python 3.11.4   (2023-06-06)

  > because I am using the latest: wx.python 4.2.1 (2023-06-07)
- sqlite 3.42.0   (2023-05-16, with DB-API 2.6.0)

```py
    sqlUPDPrepared = 'UPDATE settings SET title=?,LL=?,LR=?,RL=?,RR=?,distanceBack=? WHERE name=?'
    # note: no braket after SET, ...
    
    paramList = [title, LL, LR, RL, RR, distanceBack, title]   
    # note: the last parameter in the list is for the where clause!

    # note: cursor.execute expects a tuple for the 2nd parameter!*   
    updateTuple = tuple(item for item in paramList) # = (title, LL, LR, RL, RR, distanceBack, title)
    c.execute(sqlUPDPrepared, updateTuple)
```

[sqlite3](/questions/tagged/sqlite3) [python](/questions/tagged/python)

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know the 
    UPDATE query must look like `UPDATE table SET (key=value, key2=value2, ...) WHERE <condition>`

Try to modify query to something like

```
c.execute("UPDATE settings SET (title=?,LL=?,LR=?,RL=?,RR=?,distanceBack=?) WHERE name=?",(title, LL, LR, RL, RR, distanceBack, title))
```